# Передача данных в компонент vue.js

Tags: vue.js

На днях начал изучать Vue.js

Прошу  подсказать, по теме передачи данных из компонента в компонент.

**Вопрос 1**

Пример

…Шаблон…

```
<table>
<tr v-for=”das in data”>
<td v-for=”ny in das”>{{ ny }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

…Шаблон…

Значение ny – выводится, таблица строится.

При попытке вывести в ячейку данные через компонент не получается

…Шаблон…

```
<table>
<tr v-for=”das in data”>
<td v-for=”ny in das”><msgs v-bind:msg=”ny “</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

…Шаблон…

Значение ny – в компоненте выводится undefined

В обоих случаях data – входящие в текущий компонент данные, которые я передаю в следующий компонент.

```
props:
data: {
type: Array
default: [“dsfvdf”, “sdsdcdscd”,”sdcsdcsd”]
}
```

Вопрос 2
Не могу передать данные из массива faer в компонент

…Шаблон…

```
<table>
<tr v-for=”(das, index) in data”>
<td v-for=”ny in das”><msgs v-bind:msg=”ny“  v-bind:mass=”faer[index]“/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

…Шаблон…

faer - входящие в текущий компонент данные, которые я передаю в следующий компонент.

```
props:
faer: {
type: Array
default: [“121131”, “12121”,”1212121”]
}
```

- при передаче статических данных все получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передача данных в компоненты осуществляется через входные параметры.

> Входные параметры — это пользовательские атрибуты, которые вы можете
> установить на компоненте. Когда значение передаётся в атрибут входного
> параметра, оно становится свойством экземпляра компонента.

Простыми словами, чтобы осуществить передачу данных в компонент, нужно:

1. Объявить входные параметры в компоненте, который будет принимать данные, допустим объявим `msg` и `faer` в `props`:

   ```
   Vue.component('msgs', {
    props: ['msg', 'faer'],
    template: `<div><p>{{msg}}</p><ul><li v-for="item in faer">{{item}}</li></ul> 
    </div>`
   })
   ```
2. Теперь вы можете передавать данные в компонент `msgs` через пользовательские атрибуты, например передадим объявленные нами `msg` и `faer`:

   ```
   <msgs :msg="ny" :faer="faer[index]"></msgs>
   ```

> Компонент может принимать столько входных параметров, сколько
> захотите, и по умолчанию любое значение может быть передано в любой
> входной параметр. В шаблоне выше вы увидите, что мы можем получить
> доступ к этому значению в экземпляре компонента, как и к любому
> свойству `data`

Более подробно о входных параметрах можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) и [здесь](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Пример использования вышеизложенной информации в действии:

```js
Vue.component('msgs', {
  props: ['msg', 'faer'],
  template: `<div><p>{{msg}}</p><ul><li v-for="item in faer">{{item}}</li></ul></div>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [
      ['td 1 1', 'td 1 2', 'td 1 3'],
      ['td 2 1', 'td 2 2', 'td 2 3'],
    ],
    faer: [
      ['faer 1 1', 'faer 1 2', 'faer 1 3'],
      ['faer 2 1', 'faer 2 2', 'faer 2 3'],
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(das, index) in data">
      <td v-for="ny in das">
        <msgs :msg="ny" :faer="faer[index]"></msgs>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Николай, спасибо. Представление о передаче вроде начинает формироваться, но не могли бы вы ещё дать уточнение. Вопрос. В компоненте msgs приём данных осуществляется, ок, как вы и указали. Проблема в том, что в компоненте в котором я вызываю компонент msgs я не могу выполнить пункт 2 ваших указаний:  :msg="ny" :faer="faer[index]" в этом компоненте у меня нет функции data, а есть также входные параметры: props:
data: {несколько объектов} которыми я наполняю цикл for для строки а потом получая объект в строке я начинаю наполнять ячейки.

Comment: Так вот если значение я просто вывожу в ячейку {{ ny }} все ок, а если это же значение я хочу передать в компонент msgs через v-bind,  оно undefued в этом компоненте msgs, может нужно переменную  ny Объявлять в data , но тогда как в массив faer передать индекс.
}

Comment: Может так.    Входной параметр используется для передачи начального значения; дочерний компонент хочет использовать его как локальное свойство данных в дальнейшем. В этом случае лучше всего определить локальное свойство в данных, которое использует значение входного параметра в качестве начального:
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
  return {
    counter: this.initialCounter
  }
}

Comment: несмотря на количество вложений и уровень иерархии компонентов, вы всегда должны руководствоваться вышеизложенной информацией - передать данные через атрибуты дочернего компонента в родительском компоненте и обязательно объявить их в соответствующем дочернем компоненте (не в `data`, а в `props`), тогда в шаблоне дочернего компонента вы можете использовать эти данные как обычные свойства объекта `data`